# Find duplicates of characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I don't know how to create a macro to find duplicates of characters.

This picture shows the expected result.

[image]

This picture is my actual result.

[image]

This is my attempted code:

```
Sub atrod_dublikatus()
' atrod_dublikatus Macro

Dim a, b, skaits As Integer
skaits = 0

For a = 1 To 11
    For b = a + 1 To 11

        If Cells(a, 1).Value = Cells(b, 1) Then
            skait = skait + 1
            Cells(a, 2).Value = skait
            Cells(b, 2).Value = skait

        End If
    Next b
Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this, you can do it with a formula and an expanding range (Note the position of the $ sign in only one part of the range)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2)>0,VLOOKUP(A2,A:B,2,0),IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,MAX(B$1:B1)+1,""))
```

Put a heading in A1 (You need this for the formula to work)

Put the formula in B2 then drag down, see below for my test data

```
Heading 
Hello   1
World   2
Blah    3
Off 
On  
Blah    3
Blah    3
World   2
Blah    3
Hello   1
```